# LiFePO4 Battery -- Float Voltage VS Bulk Voltage for indefinite charging?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

*Some background: I am building a rudimentary UPS with a CC/CV charger connected to a battery and into the input of an inverter.*

I have a 12 V LiFePO4 battery with manufacturer's recommended charge profile of 14.6 V bulk/absorption, and 13.6 V float.

The specific charger I'm using doesn't support bulk/absorption/float profiles, but supports a CC/CV profile. I'm keeping the CC at 0.2C. The charger also requires me to set a specific voltage, so I will set the CV to either 14.6 or 13.6 V. However, I do not know which to select given my specific use case.

I want to leave the batteries attached to the charger at all times. This, I think, means I should leave the charger parked at 13.6 V indefinitely. However, the batteries will also be drained periodically (the battery attached to an inverter, the whole system being a makeshift UPS), so to promote full recharging between loads I want to leave the charger parked at 14.6 V.

Ideally, leaving the CV of the charger at 14.6 V is preferred, and I would assume that it is not detrimental considering the maximum SOC is defined by the manufacturer at 14.6 V on the battery. However, considering that the battery would be on the charger indefinitely, I'm not sure if the float voltage should be adhered -- put another way, can LiFePO4 be held at 100% SOC indefinitely? Or should the float voltage be held for extended periods?

Comment: How is the CV controlled? Via potentiometer? Digital menu? If the former, build a circuit to switch it to 13.6 V after some pre-defined time with an MCU?

Comment: @winny It's an off the shelf charger with a potentiometer to control the maximum voltage. So I can set it and forget it. I don't think the potentiometer directly controls the voltage there is probably some sort of logic involved internally. But I have no way of attaching additional controls to the system without completely tearing apart the off the shelf unit

Comment: Tearing it apart, one reststor, MCU and a MOSFET would solve it. If not, you’ll be better off accepting the low voltage set point and never reaching 100 % SOC or get another charger. There are plenty made for lead-acid with 14.4/14.6 V bulk charging and 13.6 V float.